# How encode French characters in Word.document xml file?

Tags: xml, character-encoding, ms-word

I am using Word.document xml as my template to load data to it using java, it works fine except some French characters such as é which caused the word file can not be opened, when I open the word file, I got error: "Illegal xml character, Location: line: 3, column: 18765", when I opened the file, I can see the word "André" which "é" in this case caused the problem, so basically, I need to do some encoding work before loading these French character to Word.document xml file. But there are many characters. Is there any simple way to add line of code on the word.document xml header to resolve this problem instead of using for looping to encode those all French characters one by one?

Comment: Did you solved this situation? I need to encode the document.xml from php and looking for a easy way :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest the program [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) for looking into characters.  It reports:

```
Character Properties for U+00E9
Character Name = LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
Encoding
    UTF-8 = C3, A9
    UTF-16 = 00E9
    UTF-32 = 000000E9
```

The bare E9 byte indicates that your file is saved using Latin-1, which is not the way XML files are supposed to be stored.  The parser chokes on it because that's not a valid UTF-8 syntax.  As well as the named entity you point out, the character is stored in the file using two consecutive bytes `C3` `A9`

So I have to ask how you how the file was created?

If that can't be fixed, you can address the reality by specifying the open file is being read in *Windows Latin 1* or whatever it turns out to be.  Now I don't know how your library works, but you may have to open the file first with the desired options, then pass the open stream to the XML parser.

If that's not possible, you can trancode the file first, then open the corrected one.
Read as (whatever, probaby Latin 1) and Write the same chars as UTF-8.  **caveat** look at the first few bytes of the file for a (wrong) byte order mark encoding.  That won't transcode sensibly and will need to be cut off first.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file correctly saved in UTF-8 encoding, and the char in question properly represented in that encoding?  Try looking at the file as raw text with notepad++ or other editor that gives explicit indications and control over that.

Comment: the file was saved, but can not be opened due to the error, the "é" in this case has been encoded to "xE9" which caused that error, so my java codes need to be changed to : if encounter the é, I need to convert it to "&#232" in order to open it and show é without any problem. but there are many french characters can cause this problem, I need to find a better simple way instead of using my java code to encode french character one by one. any ideas?